# GET method with another variable already attached

Tags: php

I need to pass a few GET variables through. The link I need is

index.php?type=door&qty=4

I can write this easily enough like

```
<a href="index.php?type='.$type.'&qty='.$qty.'"></a>
```

But I need to select the $qty amount fron a drop down list. So I have

```
<form name="qty" method="GET" action="../../../index.php?door-type="<?php echo $door_model; ?>">';
        <select>
<?php

    for ($front_int=1; $front_int<=99; $front_int++) 
    {
        echo'<option value="'.$front_int.'">'. $front_int . '</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="front-qty">
</form>
```

So how can I append these two values into one so that I get then $_GET them on the next page like I would with that first link I created?

Comment: try to use arrays or u can use sessions

Comment: `<select name="qty">`? And although putting type in the target URL like that will work, I think a better way is to pass the `type` on a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="type" value="$door_model" />`.

Comment: using javascript to set form action... try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If qty needs to be a select, then give that name to the select. Also, pass the other variable with a hidden field, which is pretty standard. Good luck :)

```
<form name="NOT_QTY" method="GET" action="../../../index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="door-type" value="<?php echo $door_model;?">
    <select name="qty">
<?php

    for ($front_int=1; $front_int<=99; $front_int++) 
    {
        echo'<option value="'.$front_int.'">'. $front_int . '</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="front-qty">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah perfect! hidden forms completely slipped my mind. Thanks a million.